Cross Compilation with custom Linker fails
I have to build my Rust program within a container, where I have all the build-essentials for i586 available (my target architecture is also i586).
For that reason, I have added the i586 target
rustup target add i586-unknown-linux-gnu

and configured the custom linker within the .cargo/config.toml
[target.i586-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "i586-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc"

When I have a simple hello world program, this compiles like a charm with
cargo build --target i586-unknown-linux-gnu -vvv

but when I add a few dependencies like
cargo add tokio --features full

and then run the build again I get an error:
Compiling lock_api v0.4.12
       Fresh bytes v1.6.1
       Fresh pin-project-lite v0.2.14
     Running `CARGO=/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo CARGO_CRATE_NAME=build_script_build CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=/root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/lock_api-0.4.12 CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS='Amanieu d'\''Antras <amanieu@gmail.com>' CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION='Wrappers to create fully-featured Mutex and RwLock types. Compatible with no_std.' CARGO_PKG_HOMEPAGE='' CARGO_PKG_LICENSE='MIT OR Apache-2.0' CARGO_PKG_LICENSE_FILE='' CARGO_PKG_NAME=lock_api CARGO_PKG_README='' CARGO_PKG_REPOSITORY='https://github.com/Amanieu/parking_lot' CARGO_PKG_RUST_VERSION=1.56.0 CARGO_PKG_VERSION=0.4.12 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR=0 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MINOR=4 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PATCH=12 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PRE='' LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/debug/deps:/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib' /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name build_script_build --edition=2021 /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/lock_api-0.4.12/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=116 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 --cfg 'feature="atomic_usize"' --cfg 'feature="default"' -C metadata=ea001e3489a366f2 -C extra-filename=-ea001e3489a366f2 --out-dir /workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/debug/build/lock_api-ea001e3489a366f2 -L dependency=/workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/debug/deps --extern autocfg=/workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/debug/deps/libautocfg-63e9e1fc11fbb971.rlib --cap-lints warn`
error: linker `cc` not found
  |
  = note: No such file or directory (os error 2)

Comparing the (verbose) output of a successful build (without the tokio dependency):
 Running `CARGO=/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo CARGO_BIN_NAME=database-handler CARGO_CRATE_NAME=database_handler CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=/workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS='' CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION='' CARGO_PKG_HOMEPAGE='' CARGO_PKG_LICENSE='' CARGO_PKG_LICENSE_FILE='' CARGO_PKG_NAME=database-handler CARGO_PKG_README='' CARGO_PKG_REPOSITORY='' CARGO_PKG_RUST_VERSION='' CARGO_PKG_VERSION=0.1.0 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR=0 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MINOR=1 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PATCH=0 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PRE='' CARGO_PRIMARY_PACKAGE=1 LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/debug/deps:/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib' /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name database_handler --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=116 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=e0869970d96f9bc8 -C extra-filename=-e0869970d96f9bc8 --out-dir /workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/i586-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps --target i586-unknown-linux-gnu -C linker=i586-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc -C incremental=/workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/i586-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/incremental -L dependency=/workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/i586-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps -L dependency=/workspace/fds/FdsFadcR2/workspace/database-handler/target/debug/deps`
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.17s

What I can clearly see, is that with the tokio library in place, cargo executes without any special linker flag. This will obviously fail because I have no other linker installed. The simple hello-world program output shows that -C linker=i586-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc is present.
Why is the linker not used in the bigger example and what to do against that?
